# OSX Installing Rsymphony - linking headers and libs

Tags: r, macos, failed-installation

symphony is correctly installed and tested in terminal. R complains about missing header and libraries when trying to install Rsymphony from source. Any pointers are HIGHLY appreciated. thank you!

- symphony installation directory: /Users/timo/Applications/symphony/
- R install command:

  `install.packages("Rsymphony", configure.args="--with-SYMPHONY-include=/Users/timo/Applications/symphony/include/ --with-SYMPHONY-lib=/Users/timo/Applications/symphony/lib",type="source")`
- results in :

  `* installing *source* package ‘Rsymphony’
  ** package ‘Rsymphony’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
  See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony’* restoring previous‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony’`

Comment: The following tutorial solved it for me: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TestDesign/vignettes/rsymphony.html

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to get `Rsymphony` installed, but finally got it working after many hours of messing around. Here's what I did, hopefully it'll save others some time. This works on Mac OS El Capitan (10.11) and R 3.3.0.

First, install the [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager if you don't already have it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Next install SYMPHONY with homewbrew. I found this to be the best approach because it puts everything in the right place:

```
brew tap coin-or-tools/coinor
brew install symphony
```

Now install `pkg-config`, a tool for querying installed libraries for when compiling software source code. Not sure if this is strictly necessary, but `pkg-config` is used in the configuration script for `Rsymphony`:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

At this point `Rsymphony` should now be able to find the necessary SYMPHONY libraries, however, I still got the following compiler error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
```

Apparently it has something to do with needing a different version of the fortran compiler. This [helpful post](http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/) with instructions for getting the correct compiler saved me. Run the following commands:

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /
```

Now, finally, you should be able to install `Rsymphony` with:

```
install.packages("Rsymphony", type = "source")
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

- I have found the solution in this link (...I got RSymphony to install, but it involved some hacking ...)
  [Installing RSymphony using RStudio on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215523/installing-rsymphony-using-rstudio-on-macos)
- I had also this issue: ..no checking for COIN-OR package CoinUtils... and it was solved by "export PKG_CONFIG=/usr/local/bin/pkg-config; export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/"