# Installing RSymphony using RStudio on macOS

Tags: r, macos, package

I am trying to install the package `RSymphony` using `RStudio` in my MAC (to afterwards be able to install the package `fPortfolio`). After accepting with `"Y"` to install the package from the source, I get the message:

```
> package 'Rsymphony' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.

> See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.

> ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Rsymphony'

> removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rsymphony'

> Warning in install.packages:
> installation of package 'Rsymphony' had non-zero exit status
```

I tried all the suggestions from other answers in this blog (*e.g.* using Homebrew, installing `Xcode`, etc.):

```
> brew tap coin-or-tools/coinor

> brew install symphony

> brew install pkg-config
```

But I still get the same `ERROR` message.  The one way I was successful was  installing  the same package in a Windows environment (via Parallels).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have Symphony installed. I managed to get it in stalled but R still can't seem to find the libraries and headers. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: The following tutorial solved it for me: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TestDesign/vignettes/rsymphony.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above suggestion worked great for me with the edits of:

> brew install wget
>
> wget https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/Rsymphony_0.1-28.tar.gz
>
> tar -xzvf Rsymphony_0.1-28.tar.gz

And I found the /R_symphony.cc in the src folder.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I got lots of help from the folks at https://github.com/coin-or-tools/homebrew-coinor, specifically Ted Ralphs. Here's what he figured out:

> OK, I got RSymphony to install, but it involved some hacking. For now, first grab and unpack the source with

```
wget https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/Rsymphony_0.1-25.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Rsymphony_0.1-25.tar.gz
```

> Now edit Rsymphony/configure and comment out the test for finding SYMPHONY libraries and headers, which is broken (not sure yet how to fix it).

```
#if test ${status} -ne 0; then
#  echo "Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers."
#  echo "See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>."
#  exit 1
#fi
```

> Next edit Rsymphony/R_symphony.cc and change

```
#include <coin/symphony.h>
```

> to

```
#include <symphony.h>
```

> Finally, do

```
r CMD install Rsymphony
```

> It worked for me, but if there are any additional errors they should be easy to fix. I'll try to report this to the Rsymphony guys and see if we can get it fixed.

In addition, I had to fix my fortran. These links helped with that:

1. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/
2. [OSX Installing Rsymphony - linking headers and libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129191/osx-installing-rsymphony-linking-headers-and-libs)

Comment: rrs: Thank you for your help. I got trouble starting with the first line of your proposed solution: "wget" is not a recognised command in my terminal (Mac). Is the solution you are proposing to be run via Terminal?

Comment: Yes, these commands are run on the terminal. I probably installed `wget` using homebrew.

Comment: After I edit those two files, it shows "MD5 checksum error", did you experience this also?